# PHP and executing Powershell ConfigMgr Module commands

Tags: php, powershell

I have a PowerShell script to get all Computers from a ConfigMgr 2012R2 collection. The script is working from ISE and Shell:

```
Import-Module (Join-Path (Split-Path $env:SMS_ADMIN_UI_PATH) ConfigurationManager.psd1)
cd "S01:\"
$all = Get-CMDevice -CollectionName "All Systems"
foreach ($entry in $all) {
    write-host $entry.Name
}
```

As soon as I try to run the script from a PHP based website nothing happens and the Output array leaves empty. For me it seems as the module is loaded withut problems - because if I change the script to:

```
$all = Get-Command -Module ConfigurationManager
```

it pushs all available commands to the php array which is then returned to my website.

Unfortunately Get-Command does not require the execution path to be switched to the ConfigMgr site and due to that, I think that is the general problem. If I change the script to something that prints the current location (get-location) it shows me the parent-directory of the PowerShell script and not the Site that I tried to change to using cd "S01:\"

Anybody who has figured out same issues or do I forgot something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone is facing similar problems: make use of powershells "error preference" to force script-abortion on errors and use "$_" for printing out the error description of the last item of the errostack (in php you have to use print_r for the outstream of the exec function).

Following this it will give important hints. In my case it led me to a simple "access is denied" that occured because I forgot to grant appropriate SCCM-permissions to the account my webservice was running with.

Hope it helps.